# Manually Insert into Identity Framework AspNetUsers Table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-identity-2

I am implementing a new Authorization API with Identity Framework.
However, We have our users table and I am trying to add the users information into the AspNetUsers table.

Quetions

1. How to generate the GUID
2. How to convert current plain-text password to the PasswordHash
3. How/What to add data in the SecurityStamp column.

Answer (score 5):

1. You can generate `Guid` with `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`
2. You can use `PasswordHasher` int `UserManager` like this `UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(password)`
3. You insert any random `string` or a `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` in SecurityStamp. It will automatically will be updated everytime user log-ins to system.

Comment: what about adding records using SQL script ? any ideas? thanks

Comment: @CDominik this answer was for and older version of Identity. I belive you could override UserStore class and use it for custom storage/query mechanisms, like runnig manual queries or DB Schema. Not sure if this still stands for newer versions or not